# Spring Data elasticsearch _search api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data

As [elasticsearch doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/_executing_searches.html) shows that we can execute query like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "_source": ["account_number", "balance"]
}'
```

How can I do this query in spring data elasticsearch library?

Comment: I've been searching too and so far, I don't see a way to add "source" as a criteria to the NativeSearchQueryBuilder().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of release 1.2.0, it appears source filtering isn't available. It is supported within the Elasticsearch native Java API. I've created a pull request to implement _source field filtering here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/115

Comment: Thanks , finally I choose to use template query to do it